# Question about proof that every f.g. projective module over a local ring is free.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm reading the proof [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=X5MlYiyUb_YC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=finitely+generated+projective+module+over+a+local+ring+is+free&source=bl&ots=9aKgJsgkB1&sig=743znb1haDVQgCrGaQTEijuD47s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VcQWU9vbHYT-oQSFloCwDQ&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=finitely%20generated%20projective%20module%20over%20a%20local%20ring%20is%20free&f=false).

I'm at the line where they say
$$
\psi\pi(f)=\psi(f+FR)=\varphi(f)+PR.$$

Since $\psi\pi$ is surjective, it should follow that $\{\varphi(f)+PR:f\in F\}=P/PR$. I don't understand the notation $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)+PR=P$. I assume $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)+PR=\{\varphi(f)+PR:f\in F\}$? If that's a subset of $P/PR$, how can it equal $P$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This should just be a comment, but too many of these questions are left without posted answers...)

The notation $\text{im}(\varphi) + PR$ refers to the sum of the two submodules $\text{im}(\varphi)$ and $PR$ (these are subsets of $P$, not $P/PR$). Explicitly,

$$\text{im}(\varphi) + PR = \{\varphi(f) + \sum_{\text{finite}} pr \mid f \in F, p \in P, r \in R \}$$

The reason that $\text{im}(\varphi) + PR = P$, is the equality $\{\varphi(f)+PR:f\in F\}=P/PR$, which says that $\{\varphi(f)\}$ forms a complete set of coset representatives of $PR$ in $P$, so every element of $P$ is a sum of some $\varphi(f)$ with an element of $PR$.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought the $+$ was still being used for the coset notation in $P/PR$ like in the previous line, not just a normal sum of modules in $P$.

Comment: Yes, overloading the operator $+$ can be confusing at times. Thanks for accepting the answer, and saving this question from the unanswered queue